# Error: Argument 'TodoListController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs-directive, umbraco

Please please help!!!

I have simple program but keep getting error. I dont know if i have to define any .js file in manifest.angular as well??
i have seen people sharing examples from old angularjs. so please help. I have got assignment to do. Thanks

todo.js

```
angular.module('todoApp', [])
    .controller('TodoListController', function () {
        var todoList = this;
        todoList.todos = [
            { text: 'learn AngularJS', done: true },
            { text: 'build an AngularJS app', done: false }];

        todoList.addTodo = function () {
            todoList.todos.push({ text: todoList.todoText, done: false });
            todoList.todoText = '';
        };

        todoList.remaining = function () {
            var count = 0;
            angular.forEach(todoList.todos, function (todo) {
                count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
            });
            return count;
        };

        todoList.archive = function () {
            var oldTodos = todoList.todos;
            todoList.todos = [];
            angular.forEach(oldTodos, function (todo) {
                if (!todo.done) todoList.todos.push(todo);
            });
        };
    });
```

index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/App_Plugins/TheDashboard/backoffice/HomeDashboard/todo.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/App_Plugins/TheDashboard/backoffice/HomeDashboard/todo.css">
    
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Todo</h2>
    <div ng-controller="TodoListController as todoList">
        <span>{{todoList.remaining()}} of {{todoList.todos.length}} remaining</span>
        [ <a href="" ng-click="todoList.archive()">archive</a> ]
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="todo in todoList.todos">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
                    <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form ng-submit="todoList.addTodo()">
            <input type="text" ng-model="todoList.todoText" size="30"
                   placeholder="add new todo here">
            <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

> Blockquote

Console Error:
jquery.min.js?cdv=1:4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

angular.min.js?cdv=1:63 Error: Argument 'TodoListController' is not a function, got undefined

WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
angular.js:34191 Uncaught TypeError: window.angular.$$csp is not a function
    at angular.js:34191

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

This will happen in Umbraco when you try and bootstrap two angular modules. Umbraco has the main parent module that you will then want to bootstrap your application separately. If you don't want to do this you can just reference the Umbraco module.
 `angular.module("umbraco")` instead of `angular.module('todoApp', [])`.

Here is a good reference to get started just building property editors https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Tutorials/Creating-a-Property-Editor/.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I will have a look and get back to you.